# Streaming Video Player in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

i need a video player inside android app for live streaming.

i don't have url i am getting data as bytes,so need a player like Exoplayer to perform live streaming .

any one can suggest a video player for streaming in android.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure please look at [jwplayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/) its one of the best player for all of the platforms not only android.

https://www.jwplayer.com/

Comment: how can we apply this in android?

Comment: Ok please check the detail documentation. They have their own player and you can cast player to fragment also. you can also look at wowza Go Player SDK if you are focusing of streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is using [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

**To register the application, follow these steps.**

- Go to the Google Developers Console.
- Create a new project. ...
- On the page that appears after project creation, expand APIs & auth
  on the left sidebar. ...
- In the sidebar on the left, select Credentials. ...
- Select API key from the Add Credentials dropdown menu.